# How make two row names in the Rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataset, which has a common feature - at the end of column names (after comma) is written the group to which a specific column corresponds to. Is it possible to create a table where two row column names will be used? In an example, the first row is Up and goes Quantity, Price, Quality. Is it also possible to somehow separate by empty column/ or some bold border these 3 groups (Up, Down and Total)? I know there is `DT` library that helps to make it easier, however, I am looking for the solution using `shiny` library only.

I also found that using `tags$style()` and `CSS` can help to solve it, however not familiar with `CSS`.

```
library(shiny)

df <- structure(list(Year = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L), 
                     Week = c(0,  1, 2, 3, 4), 
                     `Quantity, Up` = c(335, 305, 740, 910, 515), 
                     `Price, Up` = c(1, 2, 5, 5, 3), 
                     `Quality, Up` = c(243, 243, 243, 12321.434052, 1706.327462), 
                     `Quantity, Down` = c(-175, -900, -205, -35, 0), 
                     `Price, Down` = c(243, 243, 1219.717851, 902.819827, 0),
                     `Quality, Down` = c(2834.205418, 243, -1219.717851, 902.819827, 0), 
                     `Quantity, Total` = c(510,  1205, 945, 945, 515), 
                     `Price, Total` = c(431, 32, 423, 342, 243), 
                     `Quality, Total` = c(24, 4, -2, 42, 1706.327462)), 
                class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
                groups = structure(list(Year = 2022L, .rows = structure(list(1:5), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",  "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("aFRR"),
    # plot graphs
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel("Up", 
               h3(helpText("aFRR Price and Quantity")),
               tableOutput("table_up"))
    )
    )
  )



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table_up <-  renderTable(df, na = "missing",align = 'c',striped = TRUE
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you asking if you can have a double header? a header that spans subcategories? The short answer is no. You can do this with DT, but not with `renderTable()`. The headers of a table are pretty much set in `renderTable()` as far as I'm concerned. And you could not do this just with css, you need to redraw the table so that the column name `Price, Up` is split into two separate html elements.

Comment: BTW, you can do this with a lot of other table packages, not just DT. Flextables, kableExtra, gt, reactable, all support grouping columns. `renderTable()` relies on `xtable`, which supports multicolumn in latex, but I haven't figured out how to translate that to html in Shiny.